# Resolving the error URI not registered in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the following error message related to the code `<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">` typed in values.xml - "URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)". This happened after I amended my code to show information in a language other than English (Spanish). Another error that comes with instances of R. in the MainActivity.java file is "Cannot resolve symbol 'R' ".I think the second error is due to the first one. I'd be thankful to any help!

Comment: please copy&paste your error log

Answer (score 0):

remove this code and rebuild your project ,and if after this your code is not working then please explain your question with some more information ,so i could be be able to help you